# Why create both index.js and Component.js for one component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While studying some projects I repeatedly find that authors follow a file structure that doesn't make sense to me without context.

For example, for any given component there would be a folder `Header`. There would be two files, one Header.js, and the other index.js (in the same subfolder). Both would `export default const`, but the index.js would also import the adjacent Header component.

What is the logic behind this structure?

Comment: try adding an example and then asking what is the logic, your question is too abroad

Answer (score 3):

This is a common pattern to avoid imports that look like this when you group things (tests, components, actions, reducers, etc...) together in sub-folders:

```
// src/
//  components/
//    Header/
//      index.js
//      Header.js
//      Header.test.js

import Header from 'components/Header/Header';
```

in favor of:

```
import Header from 'components/Header';
```

Answer (score 1):

I know at least one reason not putting component's code into `index.js`: by now Jest does not allow having several manual mocks with the same name(but different paths! see https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2070 for details).

So

```
//- src
//-- Component1
//--- __mocks__
//---- Component1.js
//--- index.js
//--- Component1.js
//-- Component2
//--- __mocks__
//---- Component2.js
//--- index.js
//--- Component2.js
```

Will give both: shorter/more readable `import`(because of `index.js`) and working manual mocks in jest(because of component file name assumed to be unique across mock files in project)

Answer (score 0):

This architecture pattern is called barrel. You can read more here: [React barrels](https://hackernoon.com/react-project-architecture-using-barrels-d086146eb0f6). The main purpose is to simplify the export of the components.

By using an `index.js` file in the root of each folder to re-export a subset of files, you can effectively create explicit public interfaces for your React modules.